# $.ajax() not working [jquery]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hey I've seen all the solutions here on StackOverflow on the topic but they seem to not work, I don't know why. I've this code inside the `$(form).submit(function(e){...});` event handler.

```js
        e.preventDefault();
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('username', username.value);
  formData.append('password', password.value);
  
  $.ajax({
   url: 'login.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
   },
   error: function() {
    console.log('fail');
   }
  })
```

By the look of things, I think the login.php is receiving the formData value because when I submit the form nothing happens.

This is the login.php

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 $password = $username = '';
 $_SESSION['user'] = '';


 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
   include_once('db.php');
   $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
   $passd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

   $passd = md5($password);

   $sql = "select * from users where username = '" . $username . "' limit 1";
   $query = mysql_query($sql);

   if($query) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $dbpass = $row['password'];
    if($password == $dbpass) {;
     $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
     header('Location: admin.php');
    } else {
     echo 'Wrong username or password!';
    }
   } else {
    echo mysql_error();
   }
  }
 }
?>
```

How do I make this work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any errors in browser console? Paste your `login.php` code too and update your question.

Comment: If `login.php` is receiving data, then it is not your ajax fault. Probably you are returning nothing in your login.php

Comment: May the docs help you: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: You didn't send any `text / json` string from server `(login.php)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', username.value);
formData.append('password', password.value);
```

and replace

```
data: formData,
```

with :

```
data: {username: username.value, password: password.value}
```

Comment: Why `data:formData` replace with that?

Comment: Not use `usually` like word here. Before arguing read the article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @yoeunes before I accept it as an answer, could you please explain to me why the FormData object did not work.

Comment: FormData is not plain object. You have to pass FormData.getAll() instead of FormData, or passing it directly as an object

Comment: do this if you want to send files with you're request with a contentType:'multipart/form-data', but for simple data use simple object ( sorry for my bad english )

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a `form`, you can `serialize()` and send data this way:

```
e.preventDefault();
var paramsToSend = {};
paramsToSend['formData'] = $('form').serialize();

$.ajax({
  url: 'login.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {params:JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)},
  contentType: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('fail');
  }
})
```

In your server-side, you can:

```
$parameters = json_decode($_POST['params']);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object works perfectly here. Here I used `dataType='json'` in ajax opts indicating that ajax expects json data from server side.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function _submit(){
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('username', 'atauruser'); //you can set your expected username
 formData.append('password', 'ataurpass'); //you can set your expected password.
 
 $.ajax({
  url: 'login.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  dataType:'json',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(response) {
   console.log(response);
   $('#response').html(response);
  },
  error: function() {
   console.log('fail');
  }
 });
}
</script>

<button class="b" id="n" onclick="_submit()">Send Data</button>

<div id="display"></div>
<p id="response"></p>
</body>
```

And your server side code simply `login.php`

```
<?php
    $incoming = array ($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
    echo json_encode($incoming);
?>
```